# Django Admin format_html_join cannot seperate with new line <br>

Tags: django, django-admin, html-escape-characters

```
format_html_join(
        '<br>', '<br><a href="{}">{}</a>', (
            (reverse("admin:research_webproductpage_change", args=[wpp.id]), wpp.title[:30]) for wpp in webproductpages
            )
        )
```

Above I am trying to add many to many links to my django admin list display which I did succesfully. But `<br>` or "\n" not working as seperators, although `<br>` is working in the second parameter. If I put `<br>` in the first parameter it appears in double quote not as an html. Or If I put "\n" it does not appear at all. 
 I want to put links row by row because o it looks better then. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mark your separator safe !

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

format_html_join(
    mark_safe('<br>'),
    '<a href="{}">{}</a>',
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
format_html_join(
        '\n', "<a href='{}'>{}</a>", (
            (reverse("admin:research_webproductpage_change", args=[wpp.id]), wpp.title[:30]) for wpp in webproductpages
            )
        )
```

Comment: `<td class="field-link_to_listings"><a href="/admin/research/webproductpage/5323/change/">Anchor Hocking 93013A Barbary </a>
<a href="/admin/research/webproductpage/41891/change/">Anchor Hocking 93013A 5 oz Bar</a></td>`  tried this already but it does not create a new line